# Necessary Bandwidth of Current Shunt Amplifier in FOC + SVPWM motor control

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, vector-control

I am designing a BLDC motor controller using sensorless FOC + SVPWM, planning to use a shunt to measure current, and using an observer to determine the rotor angle. I was wondering, what bandwidth do i need for the op amp for the shunt amplifier.

I read somewhere that the bandwidth needs to be at least 30~50 kHz. Is that true?

My Current PID loop will run at 30~50 kHz and thus the ADC will sample at 30~50 kSamples/s.
The gain for the amplifier circuit is 16, would a LM324DT be sufficient? (it has Gain Bandwidth product of 1.3MHz).

[LM324DT datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1809051220_STMicroelectronics-LM324DT_C71035.pdf)

Comment: Unless you have some estimator for phase currents, using the shunt won't give you needed measurement for FOC. However using the estimator, the rise time of the current measurement has to be very quick in order to capture the current during a small pulse window.

Comment: I am planning to use an estimator yes. What i am asking about is how much bandwidth do i need to capture the current signal correctly.